# asynchronous directory listener in java

Tags: java, asynchronous, filesystems, nio

I am trying to listen to file system changes in a specific directory, as close to pure Java as possible.

Java 1.7 offers a  [Watch Service API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) as part of Java's new [I/O library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html).
However, the native api is based on polling for batches of changes (watch keys) with the ability to block until changes arrive.

Is there a higher API that offers listening asynchronously for changes by providing an executor and a listener?

I was surprised not to find something like FlesystemChangesAsynchronousChannel.java

Comment: Just stick it into another `Thread`? Use a producer/consumer pattern with your listening `Thread` producing changed events.

Comment: this is the popular copy-paste solution, sure. But it requires some  coding to make it nice and efficient: what if I want to scale monitored paths during runtime without making new threads? I'm certain someone has released something like that before.